# Simulate "Slide to Unlock" in MobileSubstrate

Tags: cocoa-touch

There is a way to simulate the Slide To Unlock in the lockscreen? I've been looked for this in SBAwayController, but without any results :( Have anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe (if I understand your question correctly) you want to have the lockbar "unlock itself". For something like that you want to look into `SBAwayView`, not `SBAwayController`. In that class there are different methods that interact with the different lockbars. You will want to specifically look at the `SBAwayLockBar` which is a sublcass of `TPBottomLockBar` (defined in `<TelephonyUI/TPBottomLockBar.h>`)

You will have to poke around in the headers and see if there is any way to access the lockbar's Knob position.

Hope that helped at least a bit.

Comment: Thanks :) I've looked into SBAwayView :)